# Como Lanzo un scripts con argumentos desde un input en python

Tags: python, argparse

Hola estoy haciendo un programa de TKinter con un textbox y varios comandos y quiero que si pongo un comando por ejemplo print 'argumento' inicie el script llamado print.py con el argumento siguiente al print en el textbox. Quiero saber como iniciar el script con el argumento

```
#Aqui tengo un input porque todavia estoy diseñando el GUI pero seria la salida del textbox
c = input(':> ')
```

que va despues del input para iniciar el script y pasarle los argumentos

```
#codigo del ejemplo print
import argparse

P = argparse.ArgumentParser()
P.add_argument('TEXT')

args = P.parse_args()

print(args.TEXT)
```

Comment: No he entendido muy bien tu problema,  y es muy confuso ya que mezclas argparse con tkinter

Comment: basicamente el comando del print es un script aparte y quiero hacer una aplicacion donde puedes elejir mas comandos aparte de ese y pasarles los argumentos desde ahi sin usar terminal ya que quiero hacer una especie terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo entender mejor lo que quieres, dijiste que querías hacer tu propia "terminal", así que me centraré en eso. Primero olvidemos que estamos trabajando con tkinter y que el archivo es uno estático, esto para enseñar el concepto del funcionamiento.

Para ejecutar otros scripts puedes usar el módulo `subprocess` y el método `Popen`. Para esto primero crearemos una variable `comando` que contendrá el comando cual sea, yo me  he inventado uno y por esta razón no funcionará si lo pruebas.

```py
comando = "file.py --nums 1 -g" #comando que se quiere ejecutar
```

El método `Popen` recibe una lista cuyos elementos son las partes del comando, por lo que debemos de descomponerlo, aunque también se lo podemos pasar como una cadena.

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

comando = "file.py --nums 1 -g"

proceso = Popen(comando, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print(stdout)
```

Los parámetros pasados a `Popen` (`stdout` y `stderr`) indican el flujo de salida estandar y error estandar, el valor `PIPE` indica que se abrirá un pipe al flujo de entrada y error. Con el método `communicate()` del objeto devuelto por `Popen` estamos obteniendo la salida de la ejecución de nuestro comando que puede ser satisfactorio o erróneo.

Si deseas hacer la separación del comando es útil usar el módulo `shlex` y su método `split`. Esto es mucho más seguro para comandos más complejos

```py
import shlex
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

comando = "file.py --nums 1 -g"
comando = shlex.split(comando)

proceso = Popen(comando, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print(stdout)
```

El valor de la variable `comando` será lo que obtengas de tu textbox es lo único que cambiaría del código y claro, la forma en mostrar la salida del comando, yo lo hice con un simple `print` pero tu lo puedes colocar en el propio textbox :D

Comment: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida me da este error sabes porque puede ser

Comment: Eso se produce cuando lo que tratas de ejecutar no es un comando reconocido por el sistema o no es una aplicación

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--text',
                       type=str,
                       help='texto para lo que sea')


args = parser.parse_args()

print(f'La ruta del texto es: {args.text}')
```

Y ya afuera lo puedes correr algo así:

```
$ python tu_script.py --text "/ruta/del/texto"
```

Y deberías obtener algo así:

```
La ruta del texto es: /ruta/del/texto
```

Nota: **No he probado este script en algún editor o IDE**

Comment: es que es eso lo que quiero hacer pero en un textbox de TKinter pasarle 'Nombre'.py --text 'TEXTO DE EJEMPLO JAJAJJA' y que lo ejecute lo que necesito es como ejecutar el script desde el form de tk y por ejemplo sea print 'texto' al dar enter buscaria print en el textbox y lo removeria y luejo quiero que ejecute el scrip con los argumentos del textbox | y en un IDE es exactamente igual solo abres el terminal y ejecutas el comando como lo escribiste